# can't print request.responseText to page

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

my `scriptedHTTP.js` has:

```
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", "scripts/text.txt", true);
  req.send(null);
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = req.responseText;
```

when I load the page, browser console shows:

```
  XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8000/scripts/text.txt".
```

but I get nothing on the page:

how do I handle `responseText` so it shows on the page?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). `req.responseText` only it works when the load is performed successfully. You must use the [req.onreadystatechange](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) that is triggered when the load status has changed, so now you can use `req.responseText`

```
  req.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
        div.innerHTML = req.responseText;
     }
  };
```

Comment: place it after `var req = new XMLHttpRequest ();`, I recommend you go to the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) so you know more about it